# What does Resharper have against the commonly-used getRange() in Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, named-ranges, indexed-properties, resharper-9.2

Almost all of the example code online for C# Excel interop has stuff like this:

```
monthlyChartRange = _xlSheetChart.get_Range("A3", "C4");
```

Yet, Resharper turns up its nose at it and demands: "Use indexed property" If you accede to its wishes (and I love R#, so I always say, "As you wish"), it changes it to:

```
monthlyChartRange = _xlSheetChart.Range["A3", "B4"];
```

Why? How is Range better than get_Range? How is the former any more indexed than the latter?

Comment: See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/20/indexed-properties-in-c-4-0.aspx). It isn't about OO at all as mentioned in the answer, its just about cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper is trained to use properties instead of the underlying Getter because it's easier code to read and more OO-like. The property just calls the getter under the covers.

The COM port of Excel automation just exposed the Getter, even though this is not really all that OO-ish.

BTW, I recommend using [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx?gclid=Cj0KEQiApruyBRCFqoDu1pbk9rkBEiQAF8EFdUMuaFrylNInoosHDYtTODrKLuj5x96pbLmeZ_Q9lzgaAvZY8P8HAQ) instead of Office automation. It's like **ten trillion** times faster.

Comment: I love the look of hyperbole on a Friday afternoon (Your time of day may vary).

Comment: How is a 'property', a term that applies to a specific implementation of a specific programming language, "more OO-like" than a function which accomplishes the same thing (i.e., encapsulation)?  I think you've been brainwashed into an incorrect view of what object oriented programming really is.  C++ has no properties, would you say that it is less OO than e.g. C# purely based upon that?

Comment: @EdS., I didn't say that, that's just the motivation behind what Resharper did. It's for c#, not c++, so that's the target language.

Comment: @toddmo Haha no worries.  Thanks for the edit. Down-vote removed.  Have a fine weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

> Yet, Resharper turns up its nose at it and demands: "Use indexed property"

A bit of an intro - COM goes way back. You must bare in mind that COM is a binary protocol and that some COM-aware languages have no concept of properties.

COM indexed properties are generally defined like so:

```
[propget, id(DISPID_VALUE), helpstring("blah")]
HRESULT Item([in] long Index, [out, retval] BSTR* Item);
```

The dispatch ID is `DISPID_VALUE` which informs clients that this is the **default property** typically used for indexed properties.  Notice how it is defined as a *property get* but interestingly it takes a parameter `index`.  The notion of a property getter that takes **an argument** can be confusing to *some* programming languages as we shall see.

### Fully COM-compliant Client Languages

A good COM-aware client language (such as VB6; VBA; .NET) will allow you to interact with the object like so:

```
string thing = myObject.Item[2];
```

These languages sees that this particular property is a `propget` however it takes and `in` parameter.  The fact that it is marked as `DISPID_VALUE` is rather riveting because that tells COM clients that it is the default property.  Putting two and two together, clients will realise that it must be a dandy indexed property so that they can use groovy square brackets.

It's important to realise that this is just *sugar syntax*.  It's just a more convenient way to call the default indexed property.  Behind the scenes, it will call the same COM property getter method as per un-compliant languages as shown below.

### Not-so-COM-compliant Client Languages

Some programming languages (like Visual Objects 2.6), freak out (then again I freak out when I use VO) when they see a COM property that takes a parameter and so it falls back to the underlying method declaration where it essentially treats it as a method call that takes an index parameter and returns a string:

```
string thing = myObject.get_Item(2)  //  Boo!
```

These clients probably also missed the important fact that the property was marked as `DISPID_VALUE`.

Now with c#, you are arguably free to use the *method-style* operations to query a property or do as COM was designed and use index property notation.

After all, c# is OO; understands properties; understands indexers so why wouldn't you use them?

Hence why Resharper is prompting you to use the COM-preferred indexed style.  It's no different to how you would use a regular c# class.